# My car is sipping too much fuel

Tags: honda, oil-change, crv

I drive a 2003 crv with 218.556 km on its clock. I usually get around 9 kpl on highway at 80 kph but recently, i was averaging around 5.6 kpl on a 50 km trip running at an average of 70 kph. Btw, im changing my engine oil at 219.000 km, does old engine oil affects fuel consumption??

Any tips or suggestions? Thanks

Comment: Welcome to the site. Asking "*Any tips or suggestions*" is rather broad and will probably get lots of opinion responses. Tell us what you have attempted to resolve this. For instance, when was the last time the engine had a complete service (tune up)?

Comment: That's quite a change. Old oil can affect fuel consumption, but not by that much. With that many kilometers, it's probably time to replace a lot of things. Check your manual for any scheduled maintenance items (spark plugs, coolant, etc.).

Comment: It may also be worth your time to check out some of the other questions tagged under "fuel consumption" on the site.  Without more details about the vehicle and its service history, anything we say is going to be a shot in the dark.

Comment: VTC as OP has not added sufficient information to properly diagnose anything.

Comment: It never undergo a tune up since it is silky smooth when in idle. Ive changed the spark plugs, new engine oil. Still the same results. Theres no check engine lights on.

Answer (score 2):

I wouldn't expect to notice a change in fuel consumption between oil changes, much less the 60% increase described.

First, 50 km is not a very long trip; the difference between 9 k/l and 5.6 k/l is only like 3 l. Are you sure your fuel consumption measurement is accurate?

Next, was there anything different about this recent trip that may have caused an increase in fuel consumption? For example, hilly terrain, A/C on, lots of idling, extra weight in the vehicle, carrying something on the roof, parking brake engaged, towing a trailer...

If not, check for leaks: inspect fuel lines (with fuel pump running), fuel tank after filling up, etc. Often you can detect a fuel odor after driving.

Could be any number of things, or a combination.  Things like extra rolling resistance: Low tire pressure or a dragging brake. Or less common things like a slipping clutch or automatic transmission.

Time for a tune-up, maybe?

Comment: I can smell fuel odor after every trip. Is this normal bc i have a new car (chevy sonic) that does the same.

Comment: No, it's not normal to smell fuel. Fuel systems have been sealed since the early 70's.  I would check for leaks.  The tank, filler, fuel lines, hoses, etc.  Check for leaks with the fuel pump running

Comment: We checked for leaks under the car, in the injectors and in the fuel line. Still, there were no leaks.

Answer (score 0):

Engine oil can have an affect on fuel consumption yes. The components in the engine require oil to run as efficiently as possible. Fresh oil allows the components to move freely, as it reduces the amount of friction these components can experience (as tolerances are so tight).

Over time though the oil degrades. The oil loses it's ability to lubricate efficiently, meaning friction isn't being reduced as effectively as it once was. This means the components are finding it harder to move, and in turn require more power to move against the increase in friction.

Answer (score 0):

I get around 3.3 KMPL 2.0 JDM iVtec 160 BHP. I've got a short Ram intake, high performance coils, fast fuel injectors and iridium coated plugs and a super tight serpentine belt with more traction on both sides. New high endurance pulleys, water pump, belt tensioner, and I've removed all obstacles that can effect cooling the condenser and radiatior. Oh and I changed the complete AC system. 
I don't drive less that 6000 RPM on average.

Now here's what you're looking for, less fuel economy, mate just check for your air filter. Majority of the time it's driving style and air intake that does the most harm here.

2003 crv was know for petrol leaking issues. You may have a leak. Your engine chain and tensioner has to be upgraded at this point. Valve clearance has to be set right. Water pump, steering pump, all pulleys, serpentine belt, alternator, battery and terminals, along with an automatic serpentine belt tensioner. 
Get your car on a scanner while idling and while on the road. Both times check what comes up. Even a bad catalytic converter or oxygen sensors can kill fuel economy.

Comment: Which grade fuel do you use? I use American 93 or Canadian 97ron. Anything else is less than factory specs.

Comment: I use ordinary unleaded fuel. There's only 2 inthe philippines unleaded and premium. I've put it in a scanner, there were no codes showing up. And its i can smell fuel odor after any trip

Comment: Is the fuel smell coming from the front left or rear left?

Comment: From the exhaust. Idk if its normal.

Comment: That is normal, but too much smell could indicate a cylinder throwing fuel into the exhaust system.

Comment: Run this test, put the car on a hydraulic lift at 2 ft above ground, start the car, and let it run, see if any fuel drips. If this fails, we have the fuel regulator, and injectors to blame at the fuel rail assembly. First you need to let it idle later you have to give it good throttle at high revs until it shifts up a few times. But be careful not to induce too much vibrations, there is a chance of losing support and making a 2 ft jump. If you have access to a Dyno try this out there, make sure you can slot leaks on the floor.

Comment: I bought my car to our mechanic and did the same. He checked the lines and the injectors for possible leaks and we put it on a ramp, there were no leaks. But he found something (hose) disconnected. He connected it back, idk whats the purpose of that hose but its near the air filter, after he connected it back, i can feel that my car is a bit powerful on the highway though. Still, im checking on my fuel consumption.

Comment: If you have a bad catalytic converter, does the engine light flash on? I went on a shop to get my car scanned and there where no codes showing up since there were no engine light on. Btw, im already at 221,000 kms and there were no major parts that were changed except for the torque converter and alternator.

Comment: Vin, he connected the hose at the purge valve. That should fix the fuel economy for now. A bad catalytic converter does not necessarily show up until one or both of the oxygen sensors die (not slightly failing or weak). In our Honda grace CVT sport variant,we had parked it in a shitty alley for some time during a parking crisis at work. Later on found out some small mice made it in to the catalytic converter and died. Lucky our family mechanic picked up on it. Even though we send our cars to the dealership every 6 months they never did check for this

Comment: Still we cannot rule out ignition coils, spark plugs, air filter and vaccum leaks. One vaccum leak was plugged.

Comment: And stick to only premium fuel. Did you get the fuel injectors cleaned out? If not do so.

Comment: The last time my car had check engine light on was with a broken knock sensor. I've already change spark plugs and regarding the air filter, i guess i should change it? It was a long time ago since i last changed it. And about the fuel injectors? Is there a thing we can buy like a cleaning solution or something? And should i change o2 sensors?? I dont take my car to the dealership anymore because they will charge you for things they didn't even repair or tell you that you have something wrong on your car and needs to be fixed also, its very expensive.

Comment: Also, i noticed something weird. There's a moist on the tip of my exhaust. Is this normal?? And im still figuring out the whats the cause of the smell of gas. It's too much.

Comment: It's perfectly normal for the exhaust tip to be a bit moist and the engine to throw a bit of gasoline in a spray like manner from the exhaust.

Comment: Im going to change my air filter tomorrow since my dad told me it was about years ago when he last changed it. Maybe this is the cause of the bad fuel consumption. And i also read an article that having a very dirty air filter can decrease performance and increase fuel consumption. Maybe this will work. Fingers crossed.

Comment: I don't know what you read, but on June 5th, 2017, I recommend an air filter in my original answer. Maybe you overlooked.

Comment: Did you change the air element filter?

Comment: Vin, dont change the o2 sensors unless the codes are flashed on the scanner. Get the catalytic converter checked. Run a diagnosis on all the transmission solenoids. Replace the pcv (valve) and Vtec valve along with the tiny filter. If you get a chance get all pulleys to the serpentine belt inspected. Change the belt tensioner, its pulley, get a new water pump, buy a new serpentine belt, crank pulley, and power steering pump pulley, get a new engine chain and its tensioner. Correct the valves for proper gap. Get all wheel bearings tested and replaced.

Comment: Buy new rotors and new calipers with ceramic pads.

Answer (score 0):

Your O2 sensor may be dirty so the engine gets an over rich mixture. Try using an additive like the Wynns lambda sensor cleaner in your fuel.